# eclipse SVN team actions fail saying Authentication error. svn: PROPFIND of 'foo': 403 Forbidden (baar)

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I have a customized eclipse of Version: 3.7.1. With SVN 1.6 and Java 1.6.
The Subversive team provider was 0.7.9.xx.

The Team provider was working perfect and suddenly started producing the errors saying, "Authentication error.
svn: OPTIONS of 'foo': 403 Forbidden (http://baar)".

Could not find any issue in my svn authentication , and even subversive client. I also have tortoise SVN client installed and it was working perfectly all right.

1. Check annotation on a file

[image]

2. When said Yes to above.
   [image]
3. Get SVN update
   [image]

   4. Check the SVN repository, in repository browser
      [image]

Couldn't find any solution around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the Solution for this is .....

Check your eclipse.ini file probably it may be missing your java version.

Check for these lines.

```
-vm
$YOUR_JAVA_HOME/bin/javaw.exe
```

This will bring everything back to normal!!!

***PS: Not sure how did this vanished from my eclipse.inin though  ......***